# Yii - Check model relation

Tags: php, yii, relation

**Models**: Listings and Auctions
**Relation**: Auctions BELONGS_TO Listings
**Listings PK**: id
**Auctions FK**: listings_id
**Problem**: How can I get all the attributes(objects) of both tables in my VIEW if(slow/lost connection during save) the listings PK and Auction FK is not the same.
**Model(Auctions)**

```
public function relations()
{

    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'listings' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Listings', 'listing_id'),
    );

}
```

**Controller**

```
$randomListing= new RandomListingGenerator();
$randomListing=$randomListing->actionGenerate();
$profile=new Profile;
            $this->render('index', array(
                'data' => $randomListing,   
            ));
```

**Random Listing Generator**

```
class RandomListingGenerator{
    public function actionGenerate(){
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select = '*, RAND() as rand';
        $criteria->order = 'rand';
        $criteria->limit = 1;
        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->with=array(
                'listings'=>array('select'=>'id'),
        );

        return $randomListing = Auctions::model()->find($criteria);
 }
```

}

**View**

```
echo $data->listings->rooms; 
//other attributes ....
```

I got this error

**Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you need to do? And provide the relevant DB schema? What does "slow/lost connection during save" mean here?

Comment: I meant by that is when the PK(listings table) and FK(auctions table) is different or not the same during save, due to lost/slow connection.  

Sorry for vague Problem.

Comment: Use database transactions to ensure data is updated either completely or not at all.